# How to install and update flash for Chromium and Opera on Linux Mint?

Tags: chrome, adobe-flash, opera

I've tried following:

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

I've played a little with pepper-flash as well. I tried what results on Google told me. Still with no success. At the end I made it work on Chromium, but I don't really now which attempt did the trick, since I tried a lot. It is still not working in Opera.

Once it worked in both Opera and Chromium. But then, I guess after a release, it didn't worked.

Hope you can give me a correct way to update adobe flash player for Opera and Chromium - and maybe make it work in a way, so I just need to upgrade my system to automatically upgrade flash player by a new release.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Linux Mint 18.3 and installed the pepperflashplugin-nonfree package ?

If so, just uninstall the package and follow these instructions: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/11/new-pepper-flash-installer-for-chromium-firefox/